# Python-3 Open txt, multiply and get infinite decimal place

Tags: python-3.x

I am looking for a way to print all decimal places after multiply a list of numbers from a txt file,

```
def multi(nums):                                    
answer = []                                 
for i in nums:                                  
    answer.append(float(i)*3.141625) 
return answer                                   

def main():                                                                     
nums = open('test.txt', 'r')

n = []                                  

for i in nums: n += i.split()                                   

nums.close()                                    

j = multi(n)                                    

print(j)                                    

main()
```

Here is my code so far, but I cannot get all the decimal places, which is:

```
    [1.0885019848076668e+16, 1.7612332082405268e+16, 
    2.849735193048194e+16, 1.1463000884229938e+16,1.4581162367137628e+16...}
```

Another thing, if i would like to display result like:

```
    [1.0885019848076668e+16, 
     1.7612332082405268e+16, 
     2.849735193048194e+16,
     1.1463000884229938e+16,
     1.4581162367137628e+16...}
```

Could someone could give a hand to it, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally it worked like this.

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 100

def multi(nums):                                    
    answer = []                                 
    for i in nums:
    qqq = Decimal(i)*Decimal(3.141625)
    print(qqq)
return answer                                   

def main():                                                                     
nums = open('test.txt', 'r')
       n = []                                   

for i in nums: n += i.split()                                   

nums.close()                                    

multi(n)

main()
```